# Javascript websocket client adding cookie to header

Tags: javascript, cookies, websocket, header, client

I am creating a websocket upgrade request in javascript and need to add a cookie for adding an authentication token, is this possible with cross domain restrictions?  My implementation is pretty basic:

```
document.cookie="token="+authToken+";domain=www.test.com;path=/";
websocket = new WebSocket(endpoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the way how you set the cookies value.
There is no way to add the **domain** and **path** values of the cookies, they are added automatically. You should add just the **nameOfProperty** and **valueOfProperty**. See the simple example below:

```
 document.cookie = "FirstProperty=FirstPropertyValue";
 document.cookie = "SecondProperty=SecondPropertyValue";

 const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2427/health');
```